# Using ECSlidingViewController framework, how can I add a navigationcontroller to MenuViewController for a child tableview

Tags: uitableview, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm using ECSlidingViewController framework, I need to implement a table that is child of MenuViewController. when I select a row I have to go to another tableview using a navigation controller, how can I configure this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `UINavigationController` with a root view controller that is the `MenuViewController`. Then you can set that navigation controller as one of the under view controllers on the sliding view controller.